# how to handle dynamic input values in sql server 2008 query

Tags: sql-server-2008

how to handle dynamic input values in sql server 2008 query.

My scenario is in the below query is  im having two input paramanetrs passing from java through i-batis

```
 1) if i enter stlmtTransId field alone query should execute (paymentTransId  is empty now).
 2) if i enter paymentTransId field alone query should execute(stlmtTransId  is empty now).
 3) if i enter both input values query should execute for matching the two inputs.
```

at any of abovr case i need output. how to handle it.

```
  SELECT
    STLMT_TRANS.SETTLEMENT_TRANSACTION_ID
    ,STLMT_TRANS.PC_TRANSACTION_ID
    ,STLMT_TRANS.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT
    ,STLMT_TRANS.PAYMENT_AGENT_ID
    ,STLMT_TRANS.PAYMENT_AGENCY_ID
    ,STLMT_TRANS.PAYMENT_TRANS_DATE
    FROM
    T_SETTLEMENT_TRANSACTION STLMT_TRANS WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE
    STLMT_TRANS.SETTLEMENT_TRANSACTION_ID=#stlmtTransId#
    AND
    STLMT_TRANS.PC_TRANSACTION_ID=#paymentTransId#
```

Note: im using java + I-Batis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WHERE
(
 (STLMT_TRANS.SETTLEMENT_TRANSACTION_ID=#stlmtTransId#) or (#stlmtTransId# is NULL)
)
AND
(
  (STLMT_TRANS.PC_TRANSACTION_ID=#paymentTransId#) or (#paymentTransId# is NULL)
)
```

Comment: @Valex.. The above soltion is working but not as expected.. Its working if i give both the input fields.My expected scenario is 1) stlmtTransId field alone or 2)paymentTransId field alone or 3)both paymentTransId,stlmtTransId

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
STLMT_TRANS.SETTLEMENT_TRANSACTION_ID
,STLMT_TRANS.PC_TRANSACTION_ID
,STLMT_TRANS.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT
,STLMT_TRANS.PAYMENT_AGENT_ID
,STLMT_TRANS.PAYMENT_AGENCY_ID
,STLMT_TRANS.PAYMENT_TRANS_DATE
FROM
T_SETTLEMENT_TRANSACTION STLMT_TRANS WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE STLMT_TRANS.SETTLEMENT_TRANSACTION_ID = ISNULL(@stlmtTransId, STLMT_TRANS.SETTLEMENT_TRANSACTION_ID)
AND STLMT_TRANS.PC_TRANSACTION_ID = ISNULL(@paymentTransId, STLMT_TRANS.PC_TRANSACTION_ID)
```